# Is it possible to read out two groups in one command?

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I have a script, that reads and saves the user of a ADGroup and saves it as a .csv, but I Need to do it for 2 seperate groups, with the same properties. Is there a way to read out 2 groups in one PowerShell line ?

I have working code for it, but it does not seem to be a good solution

```
 Get-ADGroupmember  "Group1" | Get-ADUser|    
select GivenName,Surname,sAMAccountName
|Sort-Object Surname |
Export-Csv -Delimiter "`t" "myPath\dat.csv" 
-NoTypeInformation -Encoding     Unicode -Append

 Get-ADGroupmember  "Group2" | Get-ADUser|    
select GivenName,Surname,sAMAccountName
|Sort-Object Surname |
Export-Csv -Delimiter "`t" "myPath\dat.csv" 
-NoTypeInformation -Encoding     Unicode -Append
```

This works perfectly fine, but i would like to know, if i can reduce this to one line of Code.

Thanks for answers in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you have duplicate code for both groups. We can simply loop these commands.
(% is an alias for Foreach-Object)

```
"Group1", "Group2" | % { Get-ADGroupmember  $_ | Get-ADUser| select GivenName,Surname,sAMAccountName | Sort-Object Surname | Export-Csv -Delimiter "`t" "myPath\dat.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding Unicode -Append }
```

Technically it's one line... but not very readable. I usually prefer to use a few more lines and some variables to keep my code easier to read.

```
$Groups = "Group1", "Group2"
$path = "myPath\dat.csv"
Foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
    Get-ADGroupmember $Group | Get-ADUser | Select-Object GivenName,Surname,sAMAccountName | Sort-Object Surname | Export-Csv -Delimiter "`t" $path -NoTypeInformation -Encoding Unicode -Append
}
```

Comment: Thank, that is exactly what I wanted !